# Targeting nested array in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can someone please advise me what I'm doing wrong here?

I am retreiving some data and injecting in to a controller as 'productInfo'.

I can load in the data fine but when I want to target specific values within a ng-repeat, I'm not getting the desired result. The best I'm getting is the last set of data i the JSON.

I'm getting the JSON from the server and can change the formatting if required. I'm just starting out with Angular so apologies if there is a simple answer.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ProductStandardCtrl">
  <p>Item:</p>
    <article ng-repeat="item in items"> 
        <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" class="logo" alt="">
        <h4>{{item.title}}</h4>
    </article>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
{
"description":"Lorem Ipsum",
"headline":"Promotion headline",
"items":{
    "Standard":
        {"img":"http://placehold.it/303x152",
        "title":"Standard Product 1"
        },
    "Standard":
        {"img":"http://placehold.it/303x152",
        "title":"Standard Product 2"
        },
    "Standard":
        {"img":"http://placehold.it/303x152",
        "title":"Standard Product 3"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `items` property on your json isn't an Array, so you can't iterate over it.

The desired format should be like this:

```
{
    "description":"Lorem Ipsum",
    "headline":"Promotion headline",
    "items":[
        {
            "img":"http://placehold.it/303x152",
            "title":"Standard Product 1"
        },
        {
            "img":"http://placehold.it/303x152",
            "title":"Standard Product 2"
        },
        {
            "img":"http://placehold.it/303x152",
            "title":"Standard Product 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I see, so would ng-repeat="item in items" loop through the items array?

Comment: @Paul exactly. You can see a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1045/).

Comment: That's great thanks just what I needed - I'll read up more on Array structures. This is coming from a third party so I'll request this amendment.

Answer (score 0):

You have identical keys inside `items`. The keys must be unique:

```
"items":{
    "Standard":{
        ..
    },
    "Standard":{
        ..
    },
    "Standard":{
        ..
    }
}
```

should be something like

```
"items":{
    "Standard1":{
        ..
    },
    "Standard2":{
        ..
    },
    "Standard3":{
        ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Your point is correct, but it does not make the `ngRepeat` works, since the `items` is not an array.